# Can't create SQL events from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to create SQL events from my PHP script. I don't want to use cron. When I type this query on PhpMyAdmin everything works fine :

```
CREATE EVENT clean_followers ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 30 SECOND DO DELETE FROM `test`.`countdown`;
```

But when I use it in my PHP script it just doesn't work (mysql_query returns false). The script can connect to the database and do any other kind of queries.

Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks

Comment: We probably have a lot of ideas - if you post your code! How else are we meant to find the issue with it?

Comment: Please post the error message that has occurred - e.g. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Thanks @EdHeal I had to select the database : CREATE EVENT `test`.clean_followers ...